# Hay forma de exportar clave valor en node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

hay alguna forma de exportar un array en node js de forma dinamica.
ej yo en la variables de entorno, tengo hecho que recorra las keys requeridas y si no exite me arroje un error.

bueno en fin, queria ver si podia exportar cada key requerida de forma de array

**src/config/index.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") require("dotenv").config();

const REQUIRED_KEYS = [
  "APP_NAME",
  "APP_URL",
  "FRONTEND_URL",
  "APP_PORT",
  "MONGO_URI",
  "JWT_TOKEN",
  "JWT_EXP",
  "CORS_ORIGIN",
  "CORS_ORIGIN_IP"
];

REQUIRED_KEYS.forEach(key => {
  if (!(key in process.env)) {
    throw new Error(`Missing ${key} to environment variable`);
  }

  const key_1 = process.env[key];

  module.exports = {
    key_1
  };
});
```

**src/server.js**

```
const {APP_NAME}= require("./config");

console.log(APP_NAME);
```

yo queiro desde server.js pueda hacer un destructuring y obtener el valor de app_name de forma independiente.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero a lo mejor buscas `Object.keys(objeto)`. Obtiene todas las llaves de un objeto y las retorna como un arreglo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto un ejemplo con una de las soluciones:

```
const REQUIRED_KEYS = [
  'APP_NAME',
  'APP_URL',
  'FRONTEND_URL',
  'APP_PORT',
  'MONGO_URI',
  'JWT_TOKEN',
  'JWT_EXP',
  'CORS_ORIGIN',
  'CORS_ORIGIN_IP',
];

const EXPORTED_KEYS = {};

REQUIRED_KEYS.forEach(key => {
  if (!(key in process.env)) {
    throw new Error(`Missing ${key} to environment variable`);
  }

  EXPORTED_KEYS[key] = process.env[key];
});

module.exports = {
  ...EXPORTED_KEYS,
};
```

Saludos.

Comment: Exelente Muchisimas gracias :)